# Adding a New Element to an existing JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

i'm trying to add a json object to an existing file in node js: When a members sign up, I want his data to be added to my existing json file.  I've found on differents website some tips and code to make it happen but still, it doesnt have any effects.

My Json file look like this right now.

```
{
  "Family Name": "Vincent",
  "Name": "Test",
  "Promotion": "2A",
  "Mail": "Vincent@gmail.com",
  "Event": "FE only",
  "Password" : "test"
}
```

And I want him to look like this when he register :

```
{
  "Family Name": "Vincent",
  "Name": "Test",
  "Promotion": "2A",
  "Mail": "Vincent@gmail.com",
  "Event": "FE only",
  "Password" : "test"
},
{
  "Family Name": "Test",
  "Name": "Test",
  "Promotion": "2A",
  "Mail": "Okay@gmail.com",
  "Event": "FE only",
  "Password" : "test"
}
```

Hope you can help me. Thanks a lot !

Comment: You need an JSON array at first place. surround the content of the json file with `[ ]` , then `var a = JSON.parse`, then `a.push(newvalue)` then `JSON.stringify(a)` then save the content in the file. Otherwise you won't end up with a valid json file.

Answer (score 2):

First of all use a JSON array to maintain your data. You can use the node `fs` module for reading and updating your file. For Example:

```
const fs = require('fs');
function readFileAndSaveData(){
   try {
        let userData = fs.readFileSync('user.json');
        userData = JSON.parse(userData);
        userData.push({
          "Family Name": "Test",
           "Name": "Test",
           "Promotion": "2A",
           "Mail": "Okay@gmail.com",
           "Event": "FE only",
           "Password" : "test"
        });
        fs.writeFileSync('user.json', JSON.stringify(userData));
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use some existing libraries (ex: [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb))

and use it as below

```
const low = require('lowdb')
const FileSync = require('lowdb/adapters/FileSync')

const adapter = new FileSync('yourfile.json')
const db = low(adapter)
db
  .get('users')
  .push({ "Family Name": "Vincent", "Name": "Test", ... })
  .write()
```